# Text Bubble and Background S6 Marshmallow Update

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Ever since the update, my text background is white and the bubbles are yellow and blue only. I have no settings area like before where I can adjust it. I can change the background but that's it. I can't adjust or change the bubble or its color? It's really hard on my eyes. Is there a way to chsnge them still or do I have to download a theme? Seems silly to chsnge the theme for a text bubble option!

Answer (score 1):

I have an S5, S4, and Note 2, and I also got fed up with the Stock Messaging app.

I highly recommend using [**Textra SMS**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra&hl=en). It has about 250,000 good reviews, many of them from Samsung users.

It's not one of those apps that use data and give you a separate phone number, Textra is a replacement stock SMS app with major customization.

Here's a screenshot of the feature you seek:

[image: Google Play Image Link]
[image: Another Google Play Image Link]

I have mine set to AMOLED-friendly black since I use Samsung, and I also enjoy the "Send Delay" feature for all the times I need to fix typos after hitting send.

Hope this helps!

*Affiliation: App User*

Answer (score 0):

This is because the update now has "enhanced messaging" (you can turn on under message settings). This is just like the iMessage that the iphone has. When other android users turn this on the text colors will change and you'll be able to see if they've read your texts or not and vice versa.

Comment: Are you serious?! How did you find out about this? Post a link?